# nginx proxy long polling

Tags: nginx, long-polling

We have a web app that requires a GET endpoint (that compute a long task) to be transformed to delegate the task to a worker (with a POST endpoint to create the task that will be delegated to worker, then a GET endpoint that will return 4XX until the job is complete in which case it will return 200). However our API consumer is "dumb" and is not able to perform such a logic of POST + retry multiple GET until 200, and we would like to make nginx proxy this logic (where this downstream connection will look like a long polling) so that it just look like a single GET endpoint (as far as the dumb API consumer is concerned).

How can this be achieved?

Thank you

Comment: Write a `CGI` script in whatever language you prefer and let nginx call the script.